# Django complex query filter through reverse relationships

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I have two models:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=20, unique = True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=256, null=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name = 'friends', symmetrical=True)
```

For search purposes, I need a query to:

1. SELECT all friends and friends of friends (excluding self)
2. WHERE username__startswith(`query`) OR full_name__startswith(`query`)

I can't figure out how to do that given the structure: need to access friends, then friends of friends and reverse `User` objects. The question therefore is:
**Can I avoid looping through the results and apply a filter to make the database do the work?**

Answer (score 0):

Why is `UserProfile` a separate class? Seems like those fields belong to a `User`.

You don't ask a question, so I'm almost certainly going to provide a partial answer, at best. Hopefully it will get you started.
To access friends you could:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1)
friends = UserProfile.friends.all().prefetch_related('friends')
for friend in friends:
    f_user = friend.user
    f_friends = friend.friends.all().prefetch_related('friends')
```

This is going to be inefficient at scale, but fine for single `UserProfile`s. Otherwise a [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.functional) might be the way to go. In fact, the docs seem similar to your issue.
If you're getting `friends` from a queryset of `UserProfile`s, you should `.prefetch_related('friends')`

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...

    @cached_property
    def my_friends(self):
        return [f for f in self.friends.all().prefetch_related('friends')]
```

Using a list comprehension like this saves you having a DB hit every time, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I already used the `prefetch_related` method but the whole point of the post is to avoid looping through the results and to apply a filter to make the database do the work. In that sense I don't see how the `cached_property` helps either. I'm wondering if `annotate` can do the trick or using `Q` but don't know how! I use a separate class, because the UserProfile contains a lot of none authentication related fields to keep things separate.

Comment: So then you might want to edit your post to include a question. Perhaps, "Can I avoid looping through the results and apply a filter to make the database do the work?"

Comment: Good tip, thnx, I edited as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Since friends are `symmetrical`, perhaps this:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=<some_user>)
all_profiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(Q(user__username__startswith=query) | 
                                          Q(full_name__startswith=query)).distinct()
profile_friends = all_profiles.filter(friends=profile)
friends_of_friends = all_profiles.filter(friends__in=profile_friends)
all_friends = profile_friends | friends_of_friends
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it's pretty close. There are likely to be some duplications, so a final `distinct` may need to be applied.